# Preventing automatic backtick `

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, markdown

When I type a backtick ` it's underlined and I can press space to make it this character ´. This is annoying because I never need this when I type in markdown I only need the backtick. So I wonder how I can turn this off?

Comment: I guess you cannot turn it off, but you could press CTRL-BACKTICK, which gives an immediate backtick. (The same with SHIFT-CTRL-BACKTICK.)

Comment: @TomGewecke: You're right - tested it with an US keyboard. It only works on my german keyboard. There are both ticks on one key.

Comment: @TomGewecke: At first I thought this, too. But it is in deed CTRL. I have a similar annoying issue when working with Markdown. And this is my personal solution. Otherwise I would create accents and such instead of Markdown code.

Comment: I'm in DevonThink and FileMaker. But it's the same in TextEdit etc.

Comment: I see now, ctrl does work with that key in the german layout.  Kind of odd, as apple doesn't normally use ctrl for characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try alt/option plus shift plus `